# TextArea Swing and JavaFX select range difference

Tags: java, swing, javafx, textarea, javafx-8

Currently I'm writing an Swing application to show the source code (C++, Java, ...) inside a `JTextArea`, include *selecting* element inside the text viewer. To select, the *location offset* and *content length* of the element is used. This is my code:

```
package application;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class MainSwing {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 400);
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/application/File.cpp")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        int functionOffset = 61;
        int functionLength = 26;
        System.out.println(content.indexOf("int PlusTest(int x, int y)"));

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        JButton btn = new JButton("Select function (Swing)");
        panel.add(btn, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JTextArea area = new JTextArea(content);
        panel.add(area, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        btn.addActionListener(e-> {
            area.requestFocusInWindow();
            area.setCaretPosition(functionOffset);
            area.moveCaretPosition(functionOffset + functionLength);
        });

        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

The sample source file (saved as ANSI, CR-LF format):
[image]

```
/*---------------Arithmetic operator---------------*/

int PlusTest(int x, int y){
    int z = x + y;

    if (z > 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

**Note**: There are 2 empty line at begining of the sample code

This code worked fine, it selects the range of C++ function declaration part:
[image]

Now, I write a similar application in JavaFX 8 (Java version: 1.8.0_112):

```
package application;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            VBox root = new VBox();
            String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/application/File.cpp")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
            int functionOffset = 61;
            int functionLength = 26;
            System.out.println(content.indexOf("int PlusTest(int x, int y)"));

            Button btn1 = new Button("Select function (JavaFX)");
            TextArea area1 = new TextArea(content);
            root.getChildren().addAll(btn1, area1);

            btn1.setOnAction(e->{
                area1.selectRange(functionOffset, functionOffset + functionLength);
            });

            Scene scene = new Scene(root,800, 300);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And this is the result:
[image]

So, why there is a difference here? Did I use the wrong function?
Thanks for any help

**Edit 1**
Try this code:

```
System.out.println(content.length());
System.out.println(area1.getText().length());
```

and the result is: 157 146 in JavaFX version
In Swing version, it is: 157 157

Comment: This is not really an answer to your question, but why don't you just use something like `area1.getText().indexOf("int PlusTest(int x, int y)")` to get the correct offset of the function? This returns index 55, which seems to be the correct starting position of the function.

Comment: The above code just for ask question only. My real aplication take a C/C++ source code as input, using 3rd-party plugin (Eclipse CDT) to parse all token element inside plus its location. After that, I used this location to select range in the source viewer. Your method will not work if my source code contains 2 exactly C++ function inside 2 different class

Comment: @DVarga, the problem is that in JavaFX version, it should select "int PlusTest(int x, int y)" as in Swing version, but it does not

Comment: @DVarga, @Jonatan Stenbacka: I tried `System.out.println(content.indexOf("int PlusTest(int x, int y)"));` in both version and both print 61 as starting position

Comment: But `System.out.println(area1.getText().indexOf("int PlusTest(int x, int y)"));` in JavaFX version return 57. Maybe the method `setText()` cut off some character??

Comment: Yes, most probably  `"\r\n" (CR+LF)` will become simple `\n`, and that's where the difference comes from. `content = content.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n");` seems solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `TextArea` ignores carriage return ("\r") and uses line feed ("\n") as line separator.

To test it:

```
TextArea area1 = new TextArea("\r\n");
System.out.println((int) "\r\n".charAt(0));
System.out.println((int) "\r\n".charAt(1));

System.out.println("TextArea text length: " + area1.getText().length());

System.out.println((int) area1.getText().charAt(0));
```

and the output:

```
13
10
TextArea text length: 1
10
```

---

**Update:**

Digging up the source of `TextInputControl` lead to this part of code:

```
private static boolean isInvalidCharacter(char c, boolean newlineIllegal, boolean tabIllegal) {
    if (c == 0x7F) return true;
    if (c == 0xA) return newlineIllegal;
    if (c == 0x9) return tabIllegal;
    if (c < 0x20) return true;
    return false;
}
```

where the interesting branch is `if (c < 0x20) return true;` which means that the carriage return character is marked as invalid, therefore it is not appended to the text of the control

---

As your file uses CR+LF as line separator, if you execute the following:

```
int functionOffset = content.indexOf("int PlusTest(int x, int y)");
content = content.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n");
int functionOffset2 = content.indexOf("int PlusTest(int x, int y)");

System.out.println("Offset before: " + functionOffset + " and after: " + functionOffset2);
```

the output is:

```
Offset before: 61 and after: 57
```

Therefore, removing the CR characters from the string before adding it to the `TextArea` should solve the issue:

```
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("src/application/File.cpp")), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
content = content.replaceAll("\r\n", "\n");
```